# Javascript check if url param exists

Tags: javascript, ab-testing, vwo

I'm running an A/B test to see if showing more items is better for conversion. But it seems that the code sometimes causes errors.. But I can't find any errors and don't know when they occur.

In my test I check whether the url param IC exists and if it doesn't exists I will add this.

This is my code:

```
function checkIfAlreadyPaginated() {
    var field = 'IC';
    var url = window.location.href;
    if(url.indexOf('?' + field + '=') != -1)
        return true;
    else if(url.indexOf('&' + field + '=') != -1)
        return true;
    return false;
}

function insertParam(key, value) {
    key = encodeURIComponent (key);
    value = encodeURIComponent (value);
    
    var kvp = document.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
    if (kvp == '') {
        return '?' + key + '=' + value;
    } else {
        var i = kvp.length;
        var x;

        while (i--) {
            x = kvp[i].split('=');
    
            if (x[0] == key) {
                x[1] = value;
                kvp[i] = x.join('=');
                break;
            }
        }
    
        if (i < 0) {
            kvp[kvp.length] = [key, value].join('=');
        }
    
        return '?'+kvp.join('&');
    }
}

var itemsPerPage = 48;
if (!checkIfAlreadyPaginated()) {
    document.location.search = insertParam('IC', itemsPerPage);
}
```

Does someone spot possible issues? I'm running the test via VWO.com.

Comment: Well what is the error you're seeing?

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors, the reason I think there is an error is because the traffic in vwo.com is divided unequally, the control version - without this code - seems to get twice the traffic and the vwo.com support said that the reason should be a javascript error

Answer (score 0):

If there is a Javascript error you should see it in the browser console and share it with us.

In any case, I would do it by creating a JS Object first. I find it easier to work with.

In the following code I added the option to do the checking for multiple params of the querystring. If you only need to check the IC you can simplify it a bit. I tested it on a blank test.html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// get the current params of the querystring
var querystringItems = document.location.search.substr(1).split('&');

// create an object
var querystringObject = {};
for(i=0;i<querystringItems.length;++i) {
    param = querystringItems[i].split('=');
    querystringObject[param[0]] = param[1];
}

// Define the keys to be searched for and their default value when they are not present
var requiredKeys = {"IC":48, "test": "me"};

// Do the checking on the querystringObject for each requiredKeys
var doreload = false;
for (var key in requiredKeys) {
    if (typeof querystringObject[key] == 'undefined') {
        doreload = true;
        // Create the missing parameter and assign the default value
        querystringObject[key] = requiredKeys[key];
    }
}

// If any of the requiredKeys was missing ...
if (doreload) {
    // rebuild the querystring
    var querystring = '?';
    for (var key in querystringObject) {
        querystring+=key+'='+querystringObject[key]+'&';
    }
    querystring=querystring.substr(0,querystring.length-1);
    // reload page
    document.location.search = querystring;
}

// assign the values to javascript variables (assuming you had it like this because you needed it)
var itemsPerPage = querystringObject.IC;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to check this:

```
//get URL params into string:
paramStr = window.location.substring(window.location.indexOf('?'), window.location.length;
//turn string into array
paramArray = paramStr.split('&');
//prepare final array of params
params = {};
//prepare the index of IC parameter
icLoc = -1; //this is negative 1 so that you know if it was found or not
//for each item in array
for(var i in paramArray){
    //push its name and value to the final array
    params.push(paramArray[i].split('='));
    //if the parameter name is IC, output its location in array
    if(params[i][0] === 'IC'){
        icLoc = i;
    }
}
```

If IC is not found, icLoc will be `-1`.

If it is found, the value of IC in the URL parameters is `params[icLoc][1]`

---

Example result for query string `?foo=bar&code=cool&IC=HelloWorld`:

```
params = {'foo': 'bar', 'code': 'cool', 'IC': 'HelloWorld'}
icLoc = 2
```

---

Example for query string `?foo=bar&code=cool`:

```
params = {'foo': 'bar', 'code': 'cool'}
icLoc = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here id is the param I'm using for a test. Pass the argument which you want to check whether it exists or not.

```js
function queryParamExistUrl(param = '') {
            if (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(param) != null)
                return true
            return false
        }
        console.log(queryParamExistUrl('id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

- You are encoding the key and value using **encodeURIComponent before checking if the key already exists. but in your `insertParam` function you're not decoding the key and value
- Changing document.location.search might cause a page reload so you can use `history.pushState` insted of

```js
function updateURL(key, value) {
    var url = new URL(window.location.href);
    console.log('Current URL:', url.href);
    url.searchParams.set(key, value);
    console.log('Updated URL:', url.href);
    window.history.pushState({ path: url.href }, '', url.href);
}

if (!checkIfAlreadyPaginated()) {
    console.log('Not paginated. Updating URL.');
    updateURL('IC', itemsPerPage);
}
```